# Meteor: execute calls from client console "everywere"

Tags: meteor

Meteor is said to automagically (in most cases) figure out what code to run on the client and what code to run on the server so you could theoretically just write all your code in one .js file.

I would like to be able to write code in my browser console and have it executed pretty much as if I had put the code in a file on my server.

For example, in my browser console:

```
[20:08:19.397] Pages = new Meteor.Collection("pages");
[20:08:30.612] Pages.insert({name:"bro"});
[20:08:30.614] "sGmRrQfezZMXuPfW8"
[20:08:30.618] insert failed: Method not found
```

Meteor says "method not found" because I need to do `new Meteor.Collection("pages");` on the server.

But is there a workaround for this, whether using the above-mentioned automagic or by explicitly saying in my browser console "run the following line of code on the server!"?

Answer (score 3):

Well it doesn't "automagically" figure it out - you have to very explicitly do one of two things:

1. Separate the code into `client` and `server` directories.
2. Wrap the code in an `isClient` or an `isServer` section.

Otherwise, any code you write will execute in both environments. However, any code input by the user on the client will only be executed on the client. Meteor has been specifically designed to protect this boundary.

You can call a [method](http://docs.meteor.com/#methods_header) on the server from the client, but again the server cannot be tricked into executing client-defined functions.

In your specific example, you can always define the collection only on the client like so:

```
Pages = new Meteor.Collection(null);
```

That will allow you do freely manipulate the collection data on the client, but it will not involve the server (nothing will be stored in the db).